# How to create regex for validating user name against unicode letters in predicate in Azure B2C custom policy?

Tags: regex, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to validate a givenname and surename claims when a user inputs data while editing a profile. I use predicates attached to claim type by reference. They work great for validation of the length of a user name or against start/end whitespaces. However, I cannot create regex which accepts all Unicode letters. In Angular part of our Identity solution, to create a user by application admin, we use a pattern containing `\p{L}` which validates against Unicode letters. Now we would like to use the same pattern in custom policy, but it just doesn't work.

Any idea why `\p{L}` doesn't work in custom policy?

How to replace it with other regex?

I try this:

```xml
<Predicate Id="DoesNotContainSpecialCharacters" Method="MatchesRegex" HelpText="This field cannot contain special characters">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Id="RegularExpression">^[\p{L}]+$</Parameter>
  </Parameters>
</Predicate>
```

As a result, when entering any characters (e.g. "aaa", "123", "#$%", "ńść") into the field validated with this regex, I get an error that it doesn't match pattern. It just denies any string.

I tried marking it with unicode flag, but result is the same:

```xml
    <Parameter Id="RegularExpression">/^[\p{L}]+$/u</Parameter>
```

Comment: @Destroy666 with such regex the custom policy fails while uploading

Comment: Fails with any error or just nothing? How does other one "not work" in that case? As it'd mean it's an acceptable regex. You need to be way more accurate when describing failure.

Comment: I edited with answers to your questions

Answer (score 1):

The solution which I finally applied.

The main goal was to allow all Unicode letters plus 5 special characters. As I was not able to whitelist all letters, I changed the approach to blacklisting. I list all special characters that are not allowed. That's not ideal but enough for my needs.

```xml
<Predicate Id="DoesNotContainSpecialCharacters" Method="MatchesRegex" HelpText="This field cannot contain special characters">
  <Parameters>
    <Parameter Id="RegularExpression">^[^~`!@#$%^&amp;*\(\)+=\[\]\\{}|:;&quot;&lt;&gt;?\/]+$</Parameter>
  </Parameters>
</Predicate>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Unicode.org (V15), \p{L} property matches 136,104 Unicode characters.
The substitute class is about 2k characters that represent 522 character class ranges.
This is not as slow as would be expected. And its worth a try.

If your source is Unicode (UTF32/8), try this as an alternative,
(Copy exactly) overwrite  `[\p{L}]` with :

```
[A-Za-zªµºÀ-ÖØ-öø-ˁˆ-ˑˠ-ˤˬˮͰ-ʹͶ-ͷͺ-ͽͿΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΡΣ-ϵϷ-ҁҊ-ԯԱ-Ֆՙՠ-ֈא-תׯ-ײؠ-يٮ-ٯٱ-ۓەۥ-ۦۮ-ۯۺ-ۼۿܐܒ-ܯݍ-ޥޱߊ-ߪߴ-ߵߺࠀ-ࠕࠚࠤࠨࡀ-ࡘࡠ-ࡪࡰ-ࢇࢉ-ࢎࢠ-ࣉऄ-हऽॐक़-ॡॱ-ঀঅ-ঌএ-ঐও-নপ-রলশ-হঽৎড়-ঢ়য়-ৡৰ-ৱৼਅ-ਊਏ-ਐਓ-ਨਪ-ਰਲ-ਲ਼ਵ-ਸ਼ਸ-ਹਖ਼-ੜਫ਼ੲ-ੴઅ-ઍએ-ઑઓ-નપ-રલ-ળવ-હઽૐૠ-ૡૹଅ-ଌଏ-ଐଓ-ନପ-ରଲ-ଳଵ-ହଽଡ଼-ଢ଼ୟ-ୡୱஃஅ-ஊஎ-ஐஒ-கங-சஜஞ-டண-தந-பம-ஹௐఅ-ఌఎ-ఐఒ-నప-హఽౘ-ౚౝౠ-ౡಀಅ-ಌಎ-ಐಒ-ನಪ-ಳವ-ಹಽೝ-ೞೠ-ೡೱ-ೲഄ-ഌഎ-ഐഒ-ഺഽൎൔ-ൖൟ-ൡൺ-ൿඅ-ඖක-නඳ-රලව-ෆก-ะา-ำเ-ๆກ-ຂຄຆ-ຊຌ-ຣລວ-ະາ-ຳຽເ-ໄໆໜ-ໟༀཀ-ཇཉ-ཬྈ-ྌက-ဪဿၐ-ၕၚ-ၝၡၥ-ၦၮ-ၰၵ-ႁႎႠ-ჅჇჍა-ჺჼ-ቈቊ-ቍቐ-ቖቘቚ-ቝበ-ኈኊ-ኍነ-ኰኲ-ኵኸ-ኾዀዂ-ዅወ-ዖዘ-ጐጒ-ጕጘ-ፚᎀ-ᎏᎠ-Ᏽᏸ-ᏽᐁ-ᙬᙯ-ᙿᚁ-ᚚᚠ-ᛪᛱ-ᛸᜀ-ᜑᜟ-ᜱᝀ-ᝑᝠ-ᝬᝮ-ᝰក-ឳៗៜᠠ-ᡸᢀ-ᢄᢇ-ᢨᢪᢰ-ᣵᤀ-ᤞᥐ-ᥭᥰ-ᥴᦀ-ᦫᦰ-ᧉᨀ-ᨖᨠ-ᩔᪧᬅ-ᬳᭅ-ᭌᮃ-ᮠᮮ-ᮯᮺ-ᯥᰀ-ᰣᱍ-ᱏᱚ-ᱽᲀ-ᲈᲐ-ᲺᲽ-Ჿᳩ-ᳬᳮ-ᳳᳵ-ᳶᳺᴀ-ᶿḀ-ἕἘ-Ἕἠ-ὅὈ-Ὅὐ-ὗὙὛὝὟ-ώᾀ-ᾴᾶ-ᾼιῂ-ῄῆ-ῌῐ-ΐῖ-Ίῠ-Ῥῲ-ῴῶ-ῼⁱⁿₐ-ₜℂℇℊ-ℓℕℙ-ℝℤΩℨK-ℭℯ-ℹℼ-ℿⅅ-ⅉⅎↃ-ↄⰀ-ⳤⳫ-ⳮⳲ-ⳳⴀ-ⴥⴧⴭⴰ-ⵧⵯⶀ-ⶖⶠ-ⶦⶨ-ⶮⶰ-ⶶⶸ-ⶾⷀ-ⷆⷈ-ⷎⷐ-ⷖⷘ-ⷞⸯ々-〆〱-〵〻-〼ぁ-ゖゝ-ゟァ-ヺー-ヿㄅ-ㄯㄱ-ㆎㆠ-ㆿㇰ-ㇿ㐀-䶿一-ꒌꓐ-ꓽꔀ-ꘌꘐ-ꘟꘪ-ꘫꙀ-ꙮꙿ-ꚝꚠ-ꛥꜗ-ꜟꜢ-ꞈꞋ-ꟊꟐ-ꟑꟓꟕ-ꟙꟲ-ꠁꠃ-ꠅꠇ-ꠊꠌ-ꠢꡀ-ꡳꢂ-ꢳꣲ-ꣷꣻꣽ-ꣾꤊ-ꤥꤰ-ꥆꥠ-ꥼꦄ-ꦲꧏꧠ-ꧤꧦ-ꧯꧺ-ꧾꨀ-ꨨꩀ-ꩂꩄ-ꩋꩠ-ꩶꩺꩾ-ꪯꪱꪵ-ꪶꪹ-ꪽꫀꫂꫛ-ꫝꫠ-ꫪꫲ-ꫴꬁ-ꬆꬉ-ꬎꬑ-ꬖꬠ-ꬦꬨ-ꬮꬰ-ꭚꭜ-ꭩꭰ-ꯢ가-힣ힰ-ퟆퟋ-ퟻ豈-舘並-龎ﬀ-ﬆﬓ-ﬗיִײַ-ﬨשׁ-זּטּ-לּמּנּ-סּףּ-פּצּ-ﮱﯓ-ﴽﵐ-ﶏﶒ-ﷇﷰ-ﷻﹰ-ﹴﹶ-ﻼＡ-Ｚａ-ｚｦ-ﾾￂ-ￇￊ-ￏￒ-ￗￚ-ￜ--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
```

Note that UTF16 surrogates are not viable inside regex character classes.

Comment: Thanks, too complicated, it looks we don't need so many characters, so we change approach

Comment: @WojBronx Too complicated ? The 2k regex matches all letters within all languages Unicode supports. https://regex101.com/r/E6xMji/1 and https://regex101.com/r/Y4jAg9/1 It was derived running `\p{L}` against the 1,114,057 Unicode character set. Then reduced to class ranges. It literally matches all \p{L} Unicode. I can do the same with any Languages you want to support which will give you a subset class of characters which is smaller than 2k regex above. Make no mistake, _there is no other approach_ if your regex does not support properties.

Comment: Note that _Properties_ are binary bit-mapped tables that resolve to yes/no given the target character translation. This differs from the class of ranges approach that you'd be forced to use if your regex does not support properties. These are the only options.

Comment: can you share the script that created that list? If I would use this artpiece/abomination in a project I would want some way to verify it.